# Advanced priority queue

Tags: c++, data-structures, filter, set, priority-queue

I'm looking for an implementation of priority queue in *C++*.
Besides the basic functionality in STL *priority queue*, it requires the following methods:

1. It can remove all same elements (determined by a function) when pushing (Similar to a set)
2. It can filter out some elements (determined by another function).

Do you have some suggestions on how to implement it?

Comment: I don't see a need to downvote this question, this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Could you expand on the filtering ? Do you mean preventing elements from ever entering the queue or being able to apply a filter on an existing queue (and thus possibly several different filters over the lifetime of the queue).

Comment: For removing duplicated elements, I'm thinking of using std::priority_queue< T*, std::set< T*, dup_predicate >, cmp_predicate >. For filtering, I mean, if I pass a filter predicate, all satisfied elements will be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::set` as a priority queue without duplicates. The `top` element can be found through `rbegin()`. Asymptotic complexity is the same as for a binary heap: O(1) `top` per the Standard requirements for `rbegin`, O(lg *n*) `push` and O(lg *n*) `pop`. The constants will be higher, though.

As for the filter, I suggest you wrap `std::set` in a class with a custom `push` method (which is a good idea anyway) that runs the filtering predicate for you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath std::set also guarantees strict ordering of its elements. As long as the elements provide an appropriate std::less operation referring to their priority indicator and you want to have only unique elements there (which the OP appearantly is asking for) it should work.

Comment: One issue though: the uniqueness and the priority may require different predicates.

Comment: I like this idea. I have one more question. Can I use std::priority_queue< T*, std::set< T* >, cmp_predicate >? And I try to do the filtering inside. But I don't know how to access its internal data structure.

Comment: @TianyiLiang: no. `std::set` does not offer the right interface to be wrapped in `std::priority_queue`. And you don't need to access `std::set`'s internals to do filtering if you wrap it.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap a `priority_queue`:

```
#include <set>
#include <queue>

// Default predicate allows all objects through
template <typename T>
struct allow_any {
    bool operator()(T const&) const {
        return true;
    }
};

// F is a callable type for the filtering predicate -- either a
// function pointer, or a class having an operator()(T const&).
template <typename T, typename F = allow_any<T> >
class filtering_priority_queue {
public:
    explicit filtering_priority_queue(F f) : allow(f) {}

    void push(T x) {
        if (allow(x) && s.find(x) == s.end()) {
            q.push(x);
            s.insert(x);
        }
    }

    T const& top() const {
        return q.top();
    }

    void pop() {
        s.erase(top());
        q.pop();
    }

private:
    std::set<T> s;
    std::priority_queue<T> q;
    F allow;
};
```

Comment: For objects with identity, not requiring a copy (`std::priority_queue<T*, ...>`) may be worth it.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I should probably use `push(T const& x)` since `top()` returns a const ref, but the user should instantiate with `T*` instead of `T` if they want a `priority_queue<T*>` underneath.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it is hard to do the filtering. I mean, if I have passed a predicate, all satisfied elements will be filtered. In std::priority, such operation is not allowed.

Comment: @TianyiLiang: I don't follow sorry. Is the problem that your filtering predicate returns `true` when the item should be excluded? Just swap `true` and `false`, or use `std::logical_not()`.

Comment: This is actually the approach that I had in mind first, but its operations will be slower than my final suggestion (except `top`, which will be a little bit faster).